# How to get all H4 elements by xpath

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to Selenium and Python. I want to make a test and for this test I want to read all products name.

```
<div class="caption">
                                <h4>Okulary</h4>
                                <p>Cena: 15.54 zł</p>
                                <p>Suspendisse fringilla enim libero, vitae tincidunt sapien fringilla ac.</p>
                                <p>
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button id="add-product-5e9b68c25b809" class="btn btn-sm" role="button"
                                                    data-add-to-basket
                                                    data-product-price="15.54"
                                                    data-product-name="Okulary" disabled>Dodaj</button>
                                        </span>
                                        <input type="number" min="0" step="1" class="form-control" value="0" autocomplete="off">
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
```

and i tried with

```
products = []
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver,60)
        titles = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h4[text()]")))
        for title in titles:
            products.append(title.text)
```

but all the time I'm getting

```
 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Please add the full html or a link to it.

Comment: check if your element is present within the iframe

Comment: https://buggy-testingcup.pgs-soft.com/task_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `visibility_of_all_elements_located` to retrieve text based `//h4[text()]`but there are two `h4` invisble elements present in the DOM `Nazwa funkcjonalności:` & `Opis funkcjonalności:`. Hence the `TimeoutException` thrown by code. Try below code to resolve your exception.

```
driver.get('https://buggy-testingcup.pgs-soft.com/task_1')
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
productName=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='caption']//h4")))

for name in productName:
    print(name.text)
```

**Output:**

[image]